# How can I switch directly to a specific weapon?

Tags: pc, mass-effect-3

It seems my only way to switch weapons is to use the mouse wheel, which slowly cycles through each weapon. The <kbd>x</kbd> key also switches between the last used weapon.

However, if I want to switch from the assault rifle to the sniper rifle, a common scenario, I need to first mouse-wheel-scroll through the shotgun. Is there a way I can jump from the assault rifle to the shotgun, or any weapon to any other weapon?

Comment: I don't have PC version to confirm, but I think you can hold left shift, and then click on the weapon in the HUD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ktash's comment is correct, hold left-shift (or whatever your HUD key is) and select the weapon you'd like to switch to.

Comment: Just a heads up though... this will occasionally glitch out and weapons (as well as squadmate powers) will become unselectable. Not sure what causes it, but I've had to reload the game a few times when that has happened.